# How to select a child element in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class='myClass'>
    <h2>Another Heading</h2>
</div>
```

Suppose that I want all h2 elements that are contained within a div with class `myClass` to be underlined.

What is the appropriate CSS selector for this? Note that this is for a static CSS file, not jQuery.

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work.  Bonus points if you can tell me what this incorrect selector selects.

```
div.myClass > h2 { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: That definitely works (it definitely selects an `h2` that's a child of a `div` with class `myClass`). Do you have a doctype declaration? Is this failing in IE? Do you have any other styles that might be potentially targeting this `h2` too?

Comment: ^^ What he said. If you check in firebug/web inspector/etc., you might be able to tell if something else is overriding your style.

Comment: IE 6 and lower won't support the child selector... but it works fine in later versions and other modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work unless you have a problem with specificity (which it doesn't look like, from the code) or you are using a very old browser.

In your case, this should do the same:

```
div.myClass h2 { text-decoration: underline; }
```

You might want to see if it works.

Also, if possible... share a http://jsfiddle.net or link to your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say it looks like a [CSS **specificity** problem](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). That selector alone is correct.

Use a tool such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to inspect the `<h2>` element, and see what other CSS rules are applied.

Comment: I found the problem:  The <h2> element was nested inside a <li> element.  Any idea on how I can handle this?  Can I select all <h2> elements that are descendents of any div with class `myClass`?

Comment: Use @Jason's answer - basically, the descendant selector rather than the child selector.